# Invoke an aws lambda function n number of times (concurrently) with different parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to schedule an aws lambda function to execute every 5 minutes. I want to have 100 invocations of the lambda function (concurrently) but each invocation will pass a different parameter.

Example: consider the below lambda function which takes a number as an input.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    number = event['number']
    # some logic
```

Every five minutes, I want this function to be called with lets say these numbers [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 19, 20, ...]. The list can contain 1000 elements.

I have looked into cron expressions in scheduled CloudWatch events but that works for scheduling the execution every 5 minutes, how do i pass these 1000 elements to 1000 different invocations of the lambda function? Do I need to integrate some other AWS feature to achieve this?

Comment: What is about to have 2 different Lambdas? One is invoked through AWS CloudWatch Schule-Rule and responsible to invoke the second Lambda 1000x which is doing your desired job. (You could also put this logic into one Lambda)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a single 'controller' lambda running at 5 minute intervals (AWS events) that creates 1000 SNS messages. Each SNS message would have it's own unique parameter. The SNS topic would have a 'worker' lambda subscribed. It would automatically fire for each of the created messages. SNS and Lambda both have error handling to deal with any failures gracefully (retry).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should look at step functions.  Step functions has support for both an iterator and parallel, though I'm not sure you could combine them.